# Python: error en cl.exe al instalar pyscard

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de instalar pyscard para Python 3.5 pero me aparece el siguiente error al instalar "pip install pyscard":

> "error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory".

He probado instalando el Visual Studio 2015 pero continua apareciendo el mismo error...

Comment: Si no tienes el ejecutable `cl.exe` en el directorio `bin` donde has instalado *Visual Studio 2015*, es que no ha terminado bien la instalación. Reinstala Visual Studio.

Comment: @ChemaCortes gracias con la reinstalación de Visual Studio ha funcionado correctamente.